# WEKA - Cant read CSV generated with Python pandas

Tags: python, csv, weka

I've been working on some dataframes with Python. I load them in using readCSV(filename, index=0) and it's all fine. The files also open fine in Excel. I also opened them in notepad, and the seem alright; below is an example line:

```
851,1.218108787,0.636454978,0.269719611,-0.849476404,-0.143909689,0.050626813,-0.094248374,-0.3096134,-0.131347142,0.671271112,0.167593329,0.439417259,-0.198164647,-0.031552824,-0.215189948,-0.1791156,0.092648696,-0.107840318,-0.162596466,0.019324121,0.040572892,-0.008307331,-0.077819297,-0.023809355,-0.148229913,-0.041082835,0.138234498,-0.070986117,0.024788437,-0.050982962,0.24689969,0
```

The first column is as I understand it an index column. Then there's a bunch of Principal Components, and at the end is a 1/0.

When I try and load the file into WEKA, however, it gives me a nasty error and urges me to use the converter, saying:

```
 Reason: 
 32 Problem encountered on line: 2
```

When I attempt to use the converter with the default settings, it states a new error:

```
Couldn't read object file_name.csv invalid stream header: 2C636F6D
```

Could anyone help with any of this? I can't provide the entire data file but if requested I can try and maybe cut out a few rows and only paste those if the error still occurs. Are there any flags I need to specify when saving a file to CSV in python? At the moment I just use a .toCSV('x.csv').

Comment: did you try loading it without the index column?

Comment: Huge thanks, it worked when I deleted the Index. Can't believe I didnt try that in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the index column not having an issue would prevent weka from reading it, when you write using `pandas.to_csv()` set the `index = False`

```
df.to_csv(index = False)
```